# How to run BATCH code in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, windows, batch-file

I'd like to run some batch code when click on an button.
The thing is I want to create the batch file in VB.NET and not use external batch file.

Finally I want run this batch code - shown in an RichTextBox.

Also - is it possible to change some variables...I mean, for example

```
$program = "selectedfromlistbox" (in batch.bat)
```

depends on which "software" was selected in an ListBox.

So I need to paste the ListBox selection into batch.

Hope u understand :)
Thx for ur help!

Hannir

Comment: Look at the Process and ProcessStartInfo classes.

Comment: I will. Thx for ur advise :)

Comment: Which operating system will this run on? Windows, I assume (the syntax above looks unusual)? If so, then call cmd.exe with parameter /c and then pass the commands you wish to invoke to it. Or create a temporary batch file and call it using cmd.exe instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run batch code within your application just like that.

You should create a temporary batch file (which then can be customized with values selected in your application) and execute that using the `Process` class.

Comment: And how is that possible? Thx for your fast help!

Comment: What do you mean? Write the batch code to a file, for example using `File.WriteAllText` and then use `Process.Start` to execute the file. If you have problems with one of these steps, there are many examples out there that show you how to write a file or how to execute a batch file.

Comment: He could call individual commands by invoking cmd.exe with /c, in sequence. Not quite the same as a batch file, of course, but it can be done.

Comment: True, but that already fails if you want to `cd` before you do something or need to set an environment variable.

Comment: Agreed, yes, it is limited in use.

Comment: I got it! Thx alot!